# How can I refactor this LINQ to be more performant?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a console app that processes orders generated since 18:30 on the previous day. The method returns an array of order numbers.

The first operation is to retrieve a list of orders from a table called Docstore (which contains orders that have been printed, which are the only orders that are needed) into an array:

```
string[] orders;
using (var db = new TCRContext())
{
    var query = from docs in db.Docstore
                where docs.DateCreated >= fromDate && docs.DocumentType == "InvoiceCredit"
                select docs.PrimaryKey.Trim();
    orders = query.Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Typically there may be at most 40 such orders.  There are a couple of further considerations.  First, there's a database VIEW called MatchingCustomerOrders which JOINs Orders (from the actual Order table, not the Docstore table) onto another table CPCustomers which contains a subset of all the company's Customers who participate in this particular operation (about 90 out of 2,370).

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[MatchingCustomerOrders]
AS
SELECT 
    Orders.order_no,
    Orders.invoice_date
FROM     
    Orders INNER JOIN
    dbo.CPCustomer ON Orders.customer = dbo.CPCustomer.Customer
WHERE  
    (dbo.CPCustomer.IsDeleted = 0)
GO
```

So we only need orders that match these customers.  And we want to restrict them to those which match the invoice date parameters (i.e. from 18:30 the previous day to now) and also we don't want to process orders that have already been processed (hence the ProcessedInvoices part)

```
var query = from matches in db.MatchingCustomerOrders
            where orders.Contains(matches.order_no.Trim())  && 
            !(from processed in db.ProcessedInvoices select processed.order_no.Trim()).Contains(matches.order_no.Trim()) &&
            matches.invoice_date >= fromDate.Date && matches.invoice_date <= toDate
            select matches.order_no;
orders = query.Distinct().ToArray();
```

This is not particularly performant because the VIEW MatchingCustomerOrders has 90,000+ rows, and my suspicion is that LINQ is operating over the whole set.  I've been banging my head trying to refactor this but none of my solutions seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried SQL Server Profiler to see the actual query and runtime, as well as the bottleneck?

Comment: This trimming of `order_no` is likely to be the killer. It disables any index usage on the column. You should make sure that trimmed data are stored and remove the Trim from the statement.

Comment: The  "Date" method truncates the date to midnight so you have to add 18 hours and 30 minutes to fromDate.Date

Comment: Why are you testing `matches.invoice_date <= toDate` if you want all the records to now? Do you expect invoice_dates to be in the future?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - there are circumstances where toDate will come from a config value or otherwise calculated ... sorry, I should have explained.

Comment: @GertArnold - thanks - I'll reexamine the data and see if there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: A good start would be to post your actual query, this part: `>= fromDate && && docs.DocumentType` will not compile.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I edited the actual query to remove proprietary data and snafued the query.  Now fixed.

Comment: A couple suggestions. 1) Looks like `Docstore` can contain multiple types? I'd model that as a table-per-heirachy so you can model the FK relationships.  2) Key-less types can have FK navigations so you can join the view query to other tables. With that you should be able to build a single query and `.Include()` everything you need.